# PHP foreach array with function names and dynamically execute them

Tags: php

I want to call the function `xxx()` and execute `getCdl()`. In `getCdl()` function i want to call the method dynamically. But this gives an error `Call to undefined function trader_​cdl2crows`. But when i execute `trader_​cdl2crows()` directly it works.

How can achieve this? :)

Functions:

```
public function xxx(){
$cdls = [
    'trader_​cdl2crows',
    'trader_​cdl3blackcrows',
    'trader_​cdl3inside',
    'trader_​cdl3linestrike',
    etc,etc,etc
$result = [];
foreach ($cdls as $cdl) {
    $result[$cdl] = $this->getCdl($cdl,$ticksPerType);
}
vardump($result);
}

private function getCdl($method,$ticksPerType){
return $method(
    $ticksPerType[$this->ticks::TICK_TYPE_OPEN],
    $ticksPerType[$this->ticks::TICK_TYPE_HIGH],
    $ticksPerType[$this->ticks::TICK_TYPE_LOW],
    $ticksPerType[$this->ticks::TICK_TYPE_CLOSE]
);
}
```

Comment: @Jeto just params, for all functions the same

Comment: Is `trader_​cdl2crows` a function, or is it a method of your class? (same for others)

Comment: existing function/method perl package

Comment: There are actually weird invisible characters in your function names, try copy pasting "trader_​cdl2crows" from your sample array [here](https://mothereff.in/html-entities). This is probably your issue (I'll post this as an answer if you can confirm it). You can even put it in your URL bar / a SO comment or any text editor and see that you can hit the arrow keys twice after between `_` and `c`.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: What? You just removed indentation. I'm talking about your function names, e.g. "trader_​cdl2crows" <- this has a invinsible character in it. I'll post it as an answer and give more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function names, such as `trader_​cdl2crows`, have an [zero-width space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) right after the `_` character.

Try encoding it using [this tool](https://mothereff.in/html-entities) for instance and it will give you: `trader_&#x200B;cdl2crows` for the first function (`&#x200B;` is that zero-width char), and similar results for the rest of them. You can also notice by attempting to use arrow keys while editing these names within any input field/text editor such as a SO comment (need two "steps" to go from `_` to `c` and vice-versa).

So replace your array with this:

```
$cdls = [
  'trader_cdl2crows',
  'trader_cdl3blackcrows',
  'trader_cdl3inside',
  'trader_cdl3linestrike',
  // if you have more function names, rewrite them here
];
```

This looks the exact same but does not have the invisible characters in it.

Comment: Wow, Good find.  How did you find that ? Select->SHIFT+RIGHT?

Comment: Actually I copy-pasted OP's code into IntelliJ's text editor and these characters appear as spaces there, I was wondering why the f*** IJ added those and then I figured it out :)

Comment: pffff, that was it... coppied the function names from here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trader-cdlengulfing.php and that coused the weird characters, thanks for your help! It works